# How to create such a design

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to create such designs:

How this is possible and is it possible to do automatically from a picture?[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any application that can convert a picture to precise outlines like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a comment which tells the essentials: You must draw it.

Do it in Inkscape, Illustrator or other vector drawing program. It can take several days of intensive practicing before one can draw a coherent Bezier curve (=path) on a placed background image, but if you are not an idiot you will finally succeed.

Making it without a background image and getting it right with no edits needs years of practicing. I know persons who could do it. They would do it as well on paper or with a drawing tablet in Photoshop. They simply do not need editable curves.

It's not only pure skill, also some artistic ability is needed to be able to find fine looking simplification like in your example. I must admit I would never have invented that single curve by myself.

Insert the black background and glows as separate shapes. Programs have many effects to make such blurry patterns.